# Broadcast.emit not excluding sender in Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

Trying to display a "user is typing" message using socket.io and javascript. Thought it was going to be as easy as broadcasting the event (which in my case is a keypress on an input field), and then copying the data to a h4 tag.

The problem is broadcast.emit sends the "user is typing" text to every client, including the sender. I'll paste a snippet of my code below . Thank you in advance.

```
**server**

     const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, 'public');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
let app = express();
let server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketIO(server);
var user;
app.use(express.static(publicPath));
let usersOnline = []; //keeps track of current users online

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
let user = socket.id;
socket.emit('user', user);

    socket.id = "anon";

    socket.on('new user', function(data,callback) {
        //if user name is taken
        if(usersOnline.indexOf(data) != -1 || data == ''){
            callback(false);
        }else{
            //if username is not taken
            callback(true);
            socket.id = data;
            //pushes data(username) to data
            usersOnline.push(socket.id);
            //sends back to client usersOnline array
            io.sockets.emit('new user', {usersOnline: usersOnline, user: socket.id});
            console.log(usersOnline.length)
        }
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        usersOnline.splice(usersOnline.indexOf(socket.id), 1);
        //emits count users, sets current user
        io.sockets.emit('new user', {usersOnline: usersOnline, user: socket.id});
        console.log(usersOnline.length)

    });


    socket.on('send msg' , function(data){
        io.sockets.emit('send msg', {msg: data, user: socket.id});
    })

    socket.on('typing', function(data){
        socket.broadcast.emit('typing', data);
    })


});

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('server is running master')
});
```

**client**

```
   let user;
let isTyping = document.querySelector('#isTyping')
let welcome_header = document.querySelector("#welcome_header");

let users_online_container = document.querySelector(".users_online");


join_btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    user = input.value;
    //sets user name to input.value
    socket.emit('new user', input.value, function(data){
        if(data){
            userName_page.style.display = "none"
            chat_page.style.display = "flex";
            welcome_header.innerHTML = input.value + ' has joined the party';
            addAnimation();
        }else{
            if(input.value == ''){
                input.classList.add("input_error");
                let error_msg = document.getElementById('error_input');
                error_msg.innerHTML = '*Invalid, Please Type a Username'
                error_msg.style.display = "block";
                input.style.border = "2px solid red";

            }else{
                input.classList.add("input_error");
                let error_msg = document.getElementById('error_input');
                error_msg.style.display = "block";
                error_msg.innerHTML = "Woops, sorry but that user name is already taken, please try again";
            }

        }
    });
    socket.on('new user' , function (data){
        counter.innerHTML = (data.usersOnline.length + " Online");
        user = data.user;
        let header = document.createElement('h3');


        for(let i = 0; i < data.usersOnline.length; i++){
            users_online_container.append(header);
            header.innerHTML = data.user;
        }
    });

});
//msg send

btn_send.addEventListener('click', function(){
    socket.emit('send msg', msg_input.value);

});
//checks if enter is pressed, if so emits message to chat
function search(ele) {
    if(event.key === 'Enter') {
        socket.emit('send msg', msg_input.value);
    }
}


socket.on('send msg', function(data){
    if(data.user == user){

            msg_input.value = '';
            let p = document.createElement('p');
            receive_.append(p);
            p.innerHTML = "<span class = 'er'>" + 'You' + "</span>" + ": " + data.msg;
            p.style.textAlign = 'right';
            p.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            p.style.justifyContent = "flex-end";
            p.style.paddingRight = "2em";
        }
        else{
            msg_input.value = '';
            let p = document.createElement('p');
            receive_.append(p);
            p.innerHTML = "<span class = 'er'>" + data.user + "</span>" + ": " + data.msg;
            p.style.textAlign = 'left';
            p.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
            p.style.paddingLeft = "2em";
        };

        //makes sure scroll stays at bottom
        receive_.scrollTop = receive_.scrollHeight;
    });
function addAnimation(){
    newUser_text.classList.add("act");
}


let header = document.querySelector(".feedback");

$(document ).ready(function(){



  $(msg_input).keypress(function() {
    socket.emit('typing', user);

  });

  socket.on('typing', function(data){
    header.innerHTML = data + ' is typing...'
  })
})
```

**edit**

Alright guys, I'm going berserk trying to figure out why this isn't working. Therefore, I'm getting desperate and just decided to post my entire project, in all its sloppy glory.

If I can get some help, once again the problem I am facing now is whenever a user types, it appears on everybody. Broadcast isn't excluding the client. Thanks again to everyone who is helping out.

Comment: FYI, I would not recommend using the same message name for messages you send to both client and server.  That can get real confusing real fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/#broadcasting-messages) states:

> To broadcast, simply add a broadcast flag to emit and send method
>   calls. Broadcasting means sending a message to everyone else **except**
>   **for the socket that starts it**.

You may have other bug in you code, but `socket.broadcast.emit` will not emit to the sender.

I can only speculate what's causing you to think that socket.io isn't working. Maybe your `user` variable may be the same for all your socket connections, and that's why you think broadcast is emitting to the socket that emitted the message.

Comment: Thanks, Going to revaluate my user variable and get back to you if anything changes.